Assertion fail on xQueueSemaphoreTake for task scheduler suspended
I'm trying to debug an assertion fail which happens in my application, running with the Posix port of the kernel (I'm testing it on my PC). I have a simple thread structure, with two main threads:

one is running a loop which performs some logic and locks/unlocks a semaphore using the xSemaphoreTake and xSemaphoreGive (with portMAX_DELAY timeout) to control the access on a data buffer
the other thread is running an endless loop with a vTaskDelay(50) (it should also be calling another function but for simplicity I've replicated the issue with just the delay

If I'm understanding it correctly the vTaskDelay always call the vTaskSuspendAll() to add the task to the delayed list and then the xTaskResumeAll() to restart the scheduler; however it seems that this conflicts with the fact that the semaphore functions check for the following assert
configASSERT( !( ( xTaskGetSchedulerState() == taskSCHEDULER_SUSPENDED ) && ( xTicksToWait != 0 ) ) );

Should I be doing things differently? I've tried this with the kernel V10.4.6 and V11.0.1

It is a port problem: vTaskSuspendAll does not really suspend anything on the Linux system when Linux threads are used. I would suggest changing the INCLUDE_xTaskGetSchedulerState to 0 in the freeRTOS config file.
I had write my own Linux port as I had more problems with existing ones.
